# How to retrieve values based on Slabs using Select query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table whose structure is:

```
p_product_id
p_weight
p_rate
```

This table contains the following data:

```
p_product_id   p_weight      p_rate
1              0.250            1
1              0.500            4
1              0.750            7
1              0.900            7.5
1              1.000            10
2              0.250            2
2              0.500            3
2              1.150            10.5
3              0.700            6.5
3              0.900            7.5
```

Now when a user enters *Weight*, I need to find the rate applicable.

So if the user enters a weight of 0.600 then based on the product selected, the rate applicable is that of 0.750 that is 7 using a MySQL query.

What query should I use for retrieving this rate?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - or just wait a couple of minutes for someone with an unbelievably high rep to come along and spoon-feed you the answer.

Comment: Why 0.750 and not 0.700? 0.700 is closer by 0.600!

Comment: Re *"Slabs"*: Not *"Slaps"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this

```
SELECT `p_rate` FROM `table` WHERE `p_weight` >= 0.600 ORDER BY `p_weight` LIMIT 1
```

You select all weights greater than 0.600, sort it ascending and then select the first record

Comment: this will select `3              0.700            6.5`

Comment: I suppose the OP does want to select 6.5 instead of 7 as per the logic he has given @RaymondNijland

Comment: Thanks Manav. The code as suggested by you works but with a small modification as follows: SELECT `p_rate` FROM `table` WHERE `p_weight` >= 0.600 ORDER BY `p_weight` LIMIT 1